# How to reference all other columns in R?

Tags: r, boolean, conditional-statements, recode

I am working with data similar to the data below:

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
x1 <- c(1,1,1,1,0)
x2 <- c(0,0,1,2,2)
x3 <- c(0,0,0,0,0)
x4 <- c(0,0,0,0,0)

df <- data.frame(ID, x1, x2, x3, x4)
```

It looks like:

```
> df
  ID x1 x2 x3 x4
1  A  1  0  0  0
2  B  1  0  0  0
3  C  1  1  0  0
4  D  1  2  0  0
5  E  0  2  0  0
```

I want to create a new column, which is the product of the conditional statement: if `x1 == 1` and `all the other columns are equal to 0`, then it is coded `"Positive"`.

How can I reference all the other columns besides x1 *without* having to write out the rest of the columns in the conditional statement?

Comment: Should the rest of the values be `NA`

Comment: They can. I plan on recoding the result of the columns using the same process. So as long as the code allows for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R:

```
df$new <- ifelse(df$x1==1 &                  ## check x1 condition
                 rowSums(df[,3:5]!=0)==0),   ## add the logical outcomes by row
                 "Positive",
                 "not_Positive"))
```

The second line is a little tricky.

- `df[,3:5]` (or `df[,-(1:2)]`) selects all the columns except the first two. You could also use `subset(df,select=x2:x4)` here (although `?subset` says "*Warning*: This is a convenience function intended for use interactively ...")
- `!=0` tests whether the values are 0 or not, returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- `rowSums()` adds up the values (`FALSE`→0, `TRUE` →1)
- the row sum is zero if all of the logical values in that row are zero when converted to numeric (→ all FALSE → none are *not* equal to zero)

If there might be `NA` values then you'll need an `na.rm=TRUE` in  your `rowSums()` specification

Answer (score 2):

With `select`, we can have multiple options.  The below one is with range (`:`), In the example, the columns selected are from 'x2' to 'x4' and are in the order.  If we want to select based on some patterns, it can be done with `matches("^x[2-9]$")`.

In the below code, it is creating logical condition on the single column 'x1', and the rest of the columns `select`ed with `rowSums`, joined together with `&`, then the output is passed on the `case_when` two-sided formula as the lhs, with the replacement value as the rhs of the `~`.  By default, all other elements that doesn't satisfy the condition will be `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(new = case_when(x1 == 1 &
           rowSums(select(., x2:x4)!= 0) == 0~ 'Positive'))
# ID x1 x2 x3 x4      new
#1  A  1  0  0  0 Positive
#2  B  1  0  0  0 Positive
#3  C  1  1  0  0     <NA>
#4  D  1  2  0  0     <NA>
#5  E  0  2  0  0     <NA>
```